# Can i find my google chrome extension if it is set to private in the web store?

Tags: search, google-chrome-extension, publish, private, chrome-web-store

I can't find my Google Chrome extension in the Chrome Web Store. I have publish them 2 Weeks ago in private mode. The extension issn't for public.

I can't really make sense of the Google documents. In those it sounds like you can find the extension in the webstore as a trusted tester or member of an added google group.

But I can't find it. Only the direkt Link works.

Comment: It's not published in the web store. Only trusted users can use the direct link.